# Convert npz jax weights into keras h5 weights

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tf.keras, jax

Is there any way to convert `JAX` npz pre-trained weights into `kers/tf.keras` h5 format weights? Couldn't find anything online.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward way to convert from `npz` format to `h5` format would be to load the data into memory and then rewrite it.

Here is a brief example:

```python
import jax.numpy as jnp
from jax import random
import h5py

# Create some random weights
key = random.PRNGKey(1701)
weights = random.normal(key, shape=(100,))

# Save to an npz file
jnp.savez('weights.npz', weights=weights)

# Load the npz and convert to h5
data = jnp.load('weights.npz')
with h5py.File('weights.h5', 'w') as hf:
    hf.create_dataset('weights', data=data['weights'])
```

Note that the details of this will depend on the content of the npz file and the desired structure of the resulting h5 file.